# nested loop cell array condition Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'v a cell array containing multiple dimensional cells (rows and columns obviously) and I want some operations in a nested loop, but I want the outer loop condition for every dimension of cell,  as I'v already a nested loop.
How can I do this.  I'm working in Matlab's enviourment.
I Currently using `length(cellArray{1})` but wants to use `length(cellArray{jj})` But unfortunately inner loop can't be swap with outer loop. 
**Edit 1:**
My outer loop is changing the indexes of CellArray  and the inner loop changing the cells of cell array. What I want make my outer loop independent to inner, and the inner to handle the case.
I want to change the position of an object according to this cell array. I'v the objects cell array and its positioning cell array. I'v done this by considering the outer loop for array's indexes for each co-ordinate and the inner loop for the objects info.
**My CellArray:**

```
cellArray = 

    [251x3 double]    [263x3 double]    [276x3 double]    [290x3 double]    [305x3 double]
```

**My Code:**

```
ii=1;
while ii<=length(cellArray {1})
for jj=1:10
%operation 1
end
%operation 2
ii = ii+1;
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at `cellfun`?  That may help you.  This function operates on every element in a cell array and you provide to it a function that you want applied to each cell.  Can you give more information?  The wording of this question is unclear.

Comment: I have used `cellfun` already, `cellArray` is created by that. hOw can I use here?

Comment: @rayryeng please check the EDIT: 1

Comment: A couple of more clarifications.  I apologize but your wording is pretty confusing.  (1) "I want the outer loop condition for every dimension of the cell". In your cell array, you only have 2D matrices.  Can you clarify what you mean by "every dimension"? All of the rows and columns? Just the rows? Just the columns? (2) "My outer loop is changing indexes into CellArray and the inner loop is changing the cells": What are "indexes"? I'm confused because you can change elements in the cell array without knowing the indexes if I'm interpreting this right.  Please make the wording more clear.

Comment: OK okay, dimention means rows and columns, i.e 251x3 but all are 3D matrices. also, for every CellArray's cell, i.e CellArray{1}, the outer loop performs the operations like CellArray{1}(:,ii), where ii is the outer loop condition and jj is the inner loop condition of CelArray{jj}

Comment: How is `251 x 3` a 3D matrix?  Also, in every element of your cell array, they are **2D** matrices, so the introduction of an extra dimension is confusing.  I'm almost good in the understanding... the wording is a bit difficult.  Please apologize for any ignorance, but I've read this question probably 10 times already and I still can't ascertain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry for that as I couldn't express it very well, [251x3] is 3D as every coulmn have the coordinates of 3D space, i.e x y and z

Comment: You didn't tell me that each cell array contains spatial co-ordinates!  I thought you had to treat each element in each matrix individually.  Let's tackle this another way.  Why don't you tell me what you're trying to do?  What is the overall purpose of this code that you have presented us?  That way I have a better understanding and I may suggest a better alternative if possible.

Comment: Well, I want to change the `position` of an object according to this cell array. I'v the objects cell array and its positioning cell array. I'v done this by considering the outer loop for array's indexes for each co-ordinate and the inner loop for the objects info.

Comment: OK, how does this object look like?  I'm assuming it's in another cell array?  Is the object simply a matrix of points?  This `CellArray` structure I'm assuming are the new locations of where each point in your object will move?  Is there a 1-to-1 correspondence?  For example, in `CellArray{1}` you have 251 points.  Are there 251 points in object #1 where the i'th point in `CellArray{1}(:,i)` corresponds to shifting the i'th point for object #1?  FWIW, you should probably update your question to give more information.  It's starting to make more sense given what you have told me.

Comment: Yeah it is simply a matrix of points.

Comment: OK, but are the sizes consistent between `CellArray` and your "object" cell matrix?  For example, `CellArray` contains 5 cell matrices.  Are there 5 objects as well?  Does `CellArray{1}` have 251 points as well as your object cell matrix in cell #1?  If the answer is yes, then we can do this by avoiding `for` loops all together.  It just needs a couple of lines for set up and one call to `cellfun`.

Comment: No, the sizes aren't dependent. Its just like `Object{1}.position=CellArray{1}(:,i)`

Comment: You have confused me again.  So there is only **one** set of co-ordinates for an object?  Are you using each co-ordinate in `CellArray{1}` to move the object?  I will refrain from commenting until you update your question.  You have omitted a lot of details that are important to answering this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52530/discussion-between-rayryeng-and-ahsan-ali)